# How can I detect when a ReadOnly property has accidentally been passed by reference?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a project which is written in VB.NET. The project has several Structures which used to have writable fields. I replaced all of those fields with read-only properties, and wrote functions for creating a copy of a structure that has one of its properties changed.

I was assuming that every part of the code that attempted to write to one of these properties would become an error, and then I could simply fix all the errors by making the code call the new functions. To my dismay, it turns out that if a ReadOnly property is accidentally passed into a ByRef parameter of a function, the compiler accepts this with no warning, and the value that's assigned is silently discarded!

Here's an example:

```vb
Structure Point
    Public ReadOnly Property X As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Y As Integer
End Structure

Module Module1
    Sub IncreaseByOne(ByRef x As Integer)
        x = x + 1
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim point As New Point
        IncreaseByOne(point.X)
        Console.WriteLine($"point.X is {point.X}")
    End Sub
End Module
```

I was hoping that the line `IncreaseByOne(point.X)` would throw an error, or at least a warning, since `point.X` is read-only and it doesn't make sense to pass it by reference. Instead, the code compiles with no warnings, and the value assigned to `x` inside of `IncreaseByOne` is silently discarded, and the program prints `point.X is 0`.

How can I detect all of the places in my code where a read-only property is passed into a function that takes it by reference? The only way I can think of is to go through every read-only property that I have, find all places where that property is used as a parameter, and look to see if that parameter is ByRef. That'll be very time-consuming, but if there's no other solution, then that's what I'll do.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I'm open to installing new software in order to do this.

Comment: A structure cannot contain fields that are initialized, so why would you have a ReadOnly property in the first place since they would only ever represent the default value of the data type?

Comment: @David They can be assigned in a ctor.

Comment: Are you doing this under `Option Strict On`?  Other than that, I think you'd have to do something like an analyzer.

Comment: @Craig - I'm not familiar with the term ctor, are you referring to a constructor? I wasn't aware that structures could have constructors. Sure enough I consulted the documentation and they can. So I retract my statement.

Comment: In the Point structure, Right Click on the "X" and select "Find All References". You'll get a list down below showing you every single line of code that touches "X". Double click on one of those entries to go directly to that line. If the line is passing the value to a function, you can then Right Click on that Function name in that line of code and select "Go to Definition". This will take you to the function where you can see if it is "ByRef".

Comment: This is the sort of issue that unit testing would pick up. Not that everyone writes unit tests for every project - I don't - but a project for a real commercial product should have tests for reasons like this.

Comment: @David The property can't be assigned to, but the underlying field can be assigned to. That's how I implement things like a `WithName` method that returns a new structure with the `Name` property changed: the method clones the structure and then sets the `_Name` field on the copy.

Comment: @Craig I don't think that Option Strict On prevents this from happening, but I'll try it out. We're going to turn on Option Strict everywhere, but it's going to take us a while to reach that point.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yep, that's definitely something we're going to do in the coming weeks. The project in its current state is pretty much untestable, so we're refactoring it in order to be able to add unit tests.

Comment: @David I think "ctor" is common shorthand for constructor in C++.

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople I would strongly recommend for all of your `Structure`s to be immutable.  The rules around when a copy gets created can make mutable value types very difficult to reason about correctly.

Comment: I just confirmed that `Option Strict On` does **not** block this.  This feels like something that was done for compatibility with old VBA-heritage code which used `ByRef` by default.  I'd argue it's still a design defect, as `Option Strict` isn't intended to maintain compatibility and it's surprising that copy-in/copy-out would compile even when the back-assignment from the copy-out is inaccessible.  The behavior is not specific to `Structure`, it's also the same for `Class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Craig suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74718534/1108505), I went ahead and wrote a custom analyzer to detect when this occurs. Now, I can simply do Analyze / Run Code Analysis / On Solution, and every place that the described problem occurs gets marked with a warning such as "The property 'point.X' is read-only and should not be passed by reference."

[The entire analyzer is available on GitHub](https://github.com/tswett/FindReadOnlyByRef/blob/main/FindReadOnlyByRef/FindReadOnlyByRefAnalyzer.cs). I've copied the important part below:

```cs
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSyntax, SyntaxKind.SimpleArgument);
}

private static void AnalyzeSyntax(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    SimpleArgumentSyntax node = (SimpleArgumentSyntax)context.Node;
    SemanticModel semanticModel = context.SemanticModel;

    if (!IsByRef(node, semanticModel))
        return;

    (bool isReadOnly, string symbolType) = IsReadOnly(node, semanticModel);

    if (isReadOnly)
    {
        Diagnostic diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(
            Rule,
            node.Expression.GetLocation(),
            symbolType,
            node.Expression.GetText());
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Determine if the given argument is passed by reference.
/// </summary>
private static bool IsByRef(SimpleArgumentSyntax node, SemanticModel semanticModel)
{
    ArgumentListSyntax argumentList = (ArgumentListSyntax)node.Parent;

    if (argumentList.Parent is InvocationExpressionSyntax invocation)
    {
        SymbolInfo functionInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocation.Expression);
        if (functionInfo.Symbol is IMethodSymbol method)
        {
            IParameterSymbol thisParameter = null;

            if (node.IsNamed)
            {
                thisParameter = method.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(parameter =>
                    parameter.Name == node.NameColonEquals.Name.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                int thisArgumentIndex = argumentList.Arguments.IndexOf(node);
                if (thisArgumentIndex < method.Parameters.Length)
                    thisParameter = method.Parameters[thisArgumentIndex];
            }

            // If we couldn't find the parameter for some reason, the
            // best we can do is just accept it.
            if (thisParameter == null)
                return false;

            RefKind refKind = thisParameter.RefKind;
            if (refKind != RefKind.None && refKind != RefKind.In)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Determine if the given argument is a read-only field or property.
/// </summary>
private static (bool isReadOnly, string symbolType) IsReadOnly(SimpleArgumentSyntax node, SemanticModel semanticModel)
{
    string symbolType = "field or property";
    bool isReadOnly = false;

    if (node.Expression is MemberAccessExpressionSyntax memberAccess)
    {
        SymbolInfo memberInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(memberAccess.Name);

        if (memberInfo.Symbol is IPropertySymbol propertySymbol && propertySymbol.IsReadOnly)
        {
            symbolType = "property";
            isReadOnly = true;
        }

        if (memberInfo.Symbol is IFieldSymbol fieldSymbol && fieldSymbol.IsReadOnly)
        {
            symbolType = "field";
            isReadOnly = true;
        }
    }

    return (isReadOnly, symbolType);
}
```

Comment: Glad to see your problem solved, you can click '✔' to mark your answer as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @JiachenLi-MSFT That's a good idea. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

That's really interesting. The VB.NET Compiler really tries to make a property look like a variable. Even if I explicitly declare the property as

```vb
Structure Point
    Dim _x As Integer

    ReadOnly Property X() As Integer
        Get
            Return _x
        End Get
    End Property
End Structure
```

The code compiles and executes as before. If the property setter is added, it even works correctly!

```vb
Structure Point
    Dim _x As Integer

    Property X() As Integer
        Get
            Return _x
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _x = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure
```

With the above change, the program correctly prints 1.

Looking at the generated IL, we can see why:

```
    IL_0009: ldloca.s     point
    IL_000b: call         instance int32 VisualBasicConsoleTest.Point::get_X()
    IL_0010: stloc.1      // Store returned value in local variable
    IL_0011: ldloca.s     // load address of that local variable (and pass to function call)
    IL_0013: call         void VisualBasicConsoleTest.Program::IncreaseByOne(int32&)
    IL_0018: nop
    IL_0019: ldloca.s     point
    IL_001b: ldloc.1      // Load contents of local variable again
    IL_001c: call         instance void VisualBasicConsoleTest.Point::set_X(int32) // and call setter
```

Even though we expect an error because a property is not a value (and a byref requires a value), the compiler fakes what we *might* have intended: He actually generates a call to the getter, stores the value on the stack, passes a reference to the stack(!) to the called function and then calls the setter with that value.

This works in this simple scenario, but I agree with the commenters above, this might be very confusing when looking at it in detail. If the property is actually a computed property, the outcome is just arbitrary (try implementing the getter as `Return _x + 1`...)

C# would throw an error here, because a property is not a value and hence cannot be used as an out or ref parameter.

Comment: Your first snippet is not surprising, because it's identical to what gets created if you just declare `ReadOnly Property X As Integer`.  VB always creates a private backing variable with a leading underscore (distinct from C# which does not expose the backing variable for an auto-property).

Comment: @Craig I was expecting that the compiler maybe differentiates between an auto-property and a normal property and fails if it's _not_ an auto-property. Taking a reference to that really sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Note that pass by copy-in/copy-out is part of the VB specification for how properties interact with `ByRef` arguments, so it's not surprising that VB does this.  The only aspect that's surprising is that it will happily go forward even when there isn't an accessible setter for the copy-out part.  From the copy-in/copy-out perspective, there's no difference between an auto-property and one that is explicitly implemented, because the copy-in/copy-out doesn't care about what might be backing the property.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for clarification. That means <insert rant why VB is a bad language>? :)

Comment: I think pass by copy-in/copy-out is more good than bad, and I'm not even arguing with letting this slide with `Option Strict Off` due to compatibility for code migrated from VBA-heritage VB.  I just think that it should be blocked with `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to catch this with the compiler.  Even `Option Strict On` will allow passing a read-only property to a `ByRef` argument.  This is defined to pass by copy-in/copy-out, and it's surprising to me that the copy-out part will compile even when the `Property Set` is inaccessible.

If you want to have an automated lint-type check for this, I would imagine that a custom analyzer could find it.  I haven't worked with analyzers, so I don't have any specific suggestions for how to write one or set it up.

Otherwise, you're left to a manual check.  As was noted in a comment, you can use the "Find All References" command from Visual Studio to help with it, but this will still require a manual review of every read-only property.